# not calling kinetic.js properly?

Tags: jquery, canvas, kineticjs

I am trying literally to replicate http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/tLwSM/, but I can't do successfully. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
        <title>title</title>
        <script src="kinetic.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h4>Double-Click to create text.<br>Drag text.</h4>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script>
            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                container: 'container',
                width: 350,
                height: 350
            });
            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            stage.add(layer);

            $(stage.getContent()).on('dblclick', function (event) {
                var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
                var mouseX = parseInt(pos.x);
                var mouseY = parseInt(pos.y);
                var text = new Kinetic.Text({
                    x: mouseX,
                    y: mouseY,
                    text: "@:" + mouseX + "/" + mouseY,
                    fill: "blue",
                    draggable: true,
                });
                layer.add(text);
                layer.draw();
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The kinetic.js file I have contains code copied directly from http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js.

When I run the file, what I get appears correct visually, but it doesn't actually do anything. There are no errors in the console.log. Maybe it's because I'm running locally and I need to do something in terminal or whatnot......?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to listen to events happening on stage.
You can just write listeners like this:

```
stage.on('click', function() {
  //function code
});
```

or

```
layer.on('click', function() {
  //function code
});
```

Same goes for any kineticJS object you've got on stage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see jQuery being included in your code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="kinetic.js"></script>
```